# Selenium WD | How to call a WebElement list from a main class, while using a loop

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver, element

I can't manage to declare a WebElement List in my Main Class, and then use it in another class for some reason.

The problem : I have a loop in the Main class, because the page is re-loaded so the elements would be recognized again and again. **the WebElement List used properly by the non-main class for the first round of the loop...but not in the second time, I then get a**

> 'NoSuchElementException'

Additional info:

1. I have total 4 classes but in order remove confusion with over-info I will copy/paste only the **Main class** + **Calling to the WebElement list class**
2. Please pay attention to the **List < WebElement > list2**, this is what I have trouble with - again, only in the second run of the loop, Once the it tries to use it again - I get the above exception
3. The loop is for keep recognizing the elements once I navigate in & out of the page

***'Main' class***

```
public class SocketMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {



    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\automation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); // where the chrome drive is
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // setting an object that called "ChromeDriver" | Open the browser without doing anything

    boolean statusOfTest=true;
    WebElement Status = null;
    statusOfTest = false;

    SocketNotMain.NavigateToMarkets(driver);


    int size = 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {

    List <WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[nowrap='nowrap']>a"));

    NavigateToInstrumentsInMarkets.EnterInstrumentViaMarkets (driver,statusOfTest, size, i,list2 );
    TestClockOfInstrument.runTestClock(driver, Status);
    }

    System.out.println("Status of the test is" +statusOfTest);

}
```

}

***'Calling to the WebElement list' class***

```
   package PracticeClasses;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class NavigateToInstrumentsInMarkets {

public static boolean EnterInstrumentViaMarkets (WebDriver driver,boolean statusOfTest,int size, int i, List<WebElement>list2) throws InterruptedException
{



        try {

            size = list2.size();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            list2.get(i).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            statusOfTest = true;

        }

        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Page of instrument not found, Page not found error 404 ");
            statusOfTest = false;
        }




        // Print insturment's name

        try {
            WebElement instrumentName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='float_lang_base_1 relativeAttr']"));
            System.out.println(instrumentName.getText());
        }



        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot find instrument's name");
            statusOfTest = false;
        }




    return statusOfTest;
}
```

}

Comment: Please share the URL? I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Why do you use `findElements` in a loop?

Comment: Because I go inside a certain page, Check there something (Didn't post all classes here, so you can't see it), and then navigate back to the initial page.

If not doing it in a loop, elements won't be recognized